# SQL Syntax Error only in C# code

Tags: c#, postgresql

I have this code:

```
"SELECT tblschemeprojectpaymentgateway.paymentgatewayid, paymentgatewayname FROM " + 
"tblschemeprojectpaymentgateway INNER JOIN tblpaymentgateway ON " +
"tblschemeprojectpaymentgateway.paymentgatewayid = tblpaymentgateway.paymentgatewayid"+
"WHERE tblschemeprojectpaymentgateway.schemeprojectid=`"+
SchemeProjectID.ToString()+"`", SqlConnection1);
sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

SqlConnection1.Open();

Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader dr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();
```

which queries a Postgresql database. SchemeProjectID is a Guid. This code executes fine with the pgAdmin database query tool, but throws a syntax error in the C# code soemwhere around "tblschemeprojectpaymentgateway".

I have tried the SchemeProjectID in quotes, backtics and just as it is - with and without the .ToString().

I can not figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Please post the exact error. There are 4 `tblschemeprojectpaymentgateway`. The error is near which one of them ?

Comment: maybe **`** is the wrong symbol, it must be **'**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Classic problem when splitting strings over several lines; you're missing the space between `tblpaymentgateway.paymentgatewayid` and `WHERE`.

Answer (score 3):

To help avoid missing spaces in strings split over multiple lines, I have found it helpful to use the @ symbol before the string to take a multi line string literally. Like such:

```
string command = @"SELECT tblschemeprojectpaymentgateway.paymentgatewayid, paymentgatewayname FROM
                                tblschemeprojectpaymentgateway INNER JOIN tblpaymentgateway ON
                                tblschemeprojectpaymentgateway.paymentgatewayid = tblpaymentgateway.paymentgatewayid
                                WHERE tblschemeprojectpaymentgateway.schemeprojectid=`" + SchemeProjectID.ToString() + "`";
```

Also, you may want to look into parameterizing your statements and possibly wrapping them in stored procedures.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a space on the third line before the `WHERE`.

```
"SELECT tblschemeprojectpaymentgateway.paymentgatewayid, paymentgatewayname FROM " + 
"tblschemeprojectpaymentgateway INNER JOIN tblpaymentgateway ON " +
"tblschemeprojectpaymentgateway.paymentgatewayid = tblpaymentgateway.paymentgatewayid "+
"WHERE tblschemeprojectpaymentgateway.schemeprojectid=`"+
```